# Assign index to array, and onClick pass it based on item's position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a searchbar that shows search suggestions from an API using `.filter().includes(string)`.

In short: I need to dynamically assign index to array of search results - everytime it displays a different amount of results

If someone types 'b' it'll show all items starting with B. However, onClick it will only add the first at the top. Because I hard coded it this way. I need to find a way to set an index for each item of the search filter, and then pass it instead of [0] like so [i] (i = index that corresponds to the desireable search from array) to this function thats executed onClick

```
    const handleAdd = (e) => { // onClick={handleAdd} 
    e.preventDefault();
    setCryptolist(
      [ ... cryptolist , 
        {
      id: filteredCoins[0]['id'], // [i]
      current_price: filteredCoins[0]['current_price'], // [i]
      name: filteredCoins[0]['name'], // [i]
      symbol: filteredCoins[0]['symbol'], // [i]
      image: filteredCoins[0]['image'], // [i]
      price_change_percentage_24h: filteredCoins[0]['price_change_percentage_24h'], // [i]
      }
    ]
  )
}
```

As you can see, it's hard coded to add the item with index 0 from this array:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 'bitcoin', symbol: 'btc', name: 'Bitcoin', image: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579', current_price: 28982, …}

1: {id: 'binancecoin', symbol: 'bnb', name: 'BNB', image: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/825/large/bnb-icon2_2x.png?1644979850', current_price: 307.58, …}

2: {id: 'binance-usd', symbol: 'busd', name: 'Binance USD', image: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/9576/large/BUSD.png?1568947766', current_price: 1.001, …}

length: 3[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Please let me know if I explained the problem clearly, and how shoould I tackle it.

Lastly here's how I'm filtering the searches:

```
  const filteredCoins = coins.filter(coin =>
    coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );
```

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: It's *not* quite clear what problem you're facing, use snippets and paste a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe by hardcoding the `cryptolist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I 100% understand your problem but I think you have an component like this:

```
const CoinList = () => {
  // some code..
  const filteredCoins = /* ... */;

  const handleAdd = (e) => { /* ... */ };

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredCoins.map(coin => (
        <div key={coin.id} onClick={handleAdd}>{coin.name}</div>
      )}
    <div>
  );
}
```

You can pass the index, which is the second argument of the function passed to `map`, to `handleAdd` as seen here:

```
const CoinList = () => {
  // some code..
  const filteredCoins = /* ... */;

  const handleAdd = (e, i) => { /* use i here */ };

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredCoins.map((coin, i) => (
        <div key={coin.id} onClick={(e) => handleAdd(e, i)}>{coin.name}</div>
      )}
    <div>
  );
}
```

This will allow you to use the index `i`  in your `handleAdd` function as desired.

Comment: I think you figured it out. Sorry for being hard to understand but I find it hard to express myself in terms of code. Yes, I want to dynamically render an array and give each element an index so I can then use that index to fetch the proper div element! THANK YOU

Comment: No worries, you will get better over time. A tip from my side is: try to really extract the root issue of your problem and don't get lost in too many details (if it's not necessary). It's also helpful to have a minimal reproducable example as it's already stated in the comments of your question. It will also help yourself to get better in finding the root issue. In the end the crucial snippet that was missing for me is the render part where you actually use `.map()` and the `onClick` handler.